# Export html table into Excel using java / javascript code

Tags: java

I want to export Html table into Excel file using java or javascript.

Comment: Java and Javascript are not at all the same things, you know that ?You'll need to accept more answers, too.

Comment: *I want to export Html table into Excel file using java or javascript.* Yeah and I want to drive a Bugatti. Please ask a real question.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need this, if you are using java:

[Apache HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

(Horrible SpreadSheet Format, which always makes me chuckle)

Answer (score 2):

**Java**: you may use

[display tag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/)

or parse the HTML and go with

[POI-HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/)

**Javascript**: if you can use ActiveX there you go with

[this example](http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0122.html)

Comment: I am generating html file dynamically but i have one common table so by using it's id,can i export whole table in Excel file ?

Comment: What do you mean by "one common table" and "its id"? Please elaborate. Anyway: if you are building the HTML you may build the Excel file at the same time using POI/HSSF.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GWT, you can add this module http://code.google.com/p/gwt-table-to-excel/